# Comment traduire « what the fuck » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, registre-familier

Je ne demande pas ici un éclaicissement du sens de la locution. Je la rencontre, comme tout lecteur d'articles anglophones sur le web, assez souvent, exprimant **une interrogation mélée selon le contexte d'un mélange de colère, de surprise, voire de consternation**.

Cependant, je me retrouve périodiquement ennuyé lorsqu'il m'arrive de traduire certains textes pour des interlocuteurs francophones, et linguee ([contracté](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=wtf) ou [étendu](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=%22what%20the%20fuck%22)) ne me donne que de piètres propositions, trahissant souvent le sens originel en terme de degré de violence verbale ou de registre de langage.

**Comment la traduire en français ?** (écrit ou oral)

Quelques exemples en situation et les propositions de traduction que j'envisagerais par défaut :

> “What the fuck is going on here?” *(Putain mais qu'est-ce qui se passe ici ?)*
>
> “What the fuck, dude?” *(Hé mec, c'est quoi ce merdier ?)*

Dans ces deux exemples de traduction j'ai du *tricher* en ajoutant ce qu'il fallait pour rendre le ton initial en anglais, mais au détriment du sens, et en ajoutant sans doute des connotations inopinées. Est-ce acceptable malgré tout ?

---

En lien avec ma première question, un autre point : je fréquente les forums d'un [site](http://thedailywtf.com/Default.aspx) anglophone très connu dont l'URL comporte l'acronyme WTF, sur lequel un concept est apparu, consistant en une substantivation de cette locution, se définissant approximativement comme ceci :

> “a WTF” : *un code informatique dont la piètre construction ou un quelconque aspect repoussant provoque, chez le développeur sain, la prononciation presque instinctive et pavlovienne dudit acronyme.*

On comprendra aisément que ni la répétition de cette litanie ni l'utilisation dans des phrases françaises d'un approximatif « ouatte zeu feuque » ne soient satisfaisants. (Je ne vous parle même pas de l'adjectif *WTF-y* ou de l'autre substantif *WTF-ery*, signifiant *une situation présentant une forte tendance à produire des WTF*)

**…ou faut-il me résoudre à *ne pas* traduire ?**

Comment: Ne pas traduire me semble être une mauvaise idée. WTF est compréhensible seulement par les habitués de l'internet anglophone informel. Un francophone lisant un roman traduit ne comprendrait pas.

Comment: @mouviciel Oui, d'où ma question. Je me suis dit qu'il y avait peut-être en français une interjection ou une locution qui évoque le même sentiment, même si on s'éloigne de la traduction littérale.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Seconde réponse *(Eurêka!)***
(j'ai préféré faire une seconde réponse car elle va dans un tout autre sens que la première piste que j'avais exprimée.)

L'équivalent en français est **l'association de "*mais*" avec un juron de renforcement.**

> Mais putain ?! / *What the fuck?!*

---

La relecture des réponses proposées m'a rappelé qu'il y a une formulation bien spécifique, non pas exactement avec le simple *putain [...]?!* mais plus exactement avec *putain mais [...]?!*. Quelques exemples à l'appui, qui sonnent, je crois, bien plus juste que leurs équivalents sans le *mais* :

> Putain **mais** qu'est-ce que tu fais/fous?! / *[What] The fuck are you doing?!*
>
> Putain **mais** où vous étiez?! / *[Where] the fuck have you been?!*
>
> Putain **mais** pour qui elle se prend, celle-là?! / *Who the fuck does she think she is?!*
>
> Bordel **mais** qu'est-ce qui s'est passé?! / *What the fuck happened here?!*

On peut d'ailleurs substituer ici *Putain* avec *Bordel* et obtenir le même effet, ou inverser l'ordre des deux premiers termes :

> **Mais** putain qu'est-ce que vous attendez ?! / *[What] the fuck are you guys waiting for?!*
>
> **Mais** bordel à qui tu t'adresses exactement ?! / *Who the fuck are you even talking to exactly?!*

Ca couvre tous les cas où *what the fuck* introduit une question complète (*what the fuck is going on here?!*) et pour le cas de la simple exclamation *what the fuck?!*, on dit peut-être plus rarement *Putain mais?!* que *Mais putain?!*, cela dit, il me semble que c'est très employé et tout-à-fait équivalent à l'expression en question.

J'avoue être content d'avoir mis le doigt sur cette idée, car je pense que le *mais* est très important dans cet usage idiomatique car il n'a strictement pas le rôle habituel de marquer une opposition. Et du coup le terme *putain* n'a plus ici sa valeur d'insulte et n'est clairement adressé à aucun interlocuteur.

---

En revanche, pour être honnête, cela ne répond à aucune des deux questions secondaires. Pas d'acronyme lié à cet usage, et difficile à substantiver.

Comment: "putain", "putain con" est très méridional, il remplace alors le 'mais'

Comment: Ca fait un bail donc je ne sais même pas si vous cherchez toujours d’acronyme pour WTF, mais en ajoutant « Quelle Espèce De » devant les réponses de cl-r (Bordel/Merdier) ça donnerait « QEDB »/« QEDM », et devant votre deuxième réponse (Putain Mais) ça donnerait « QEDPM ».
Ca marcherait aussi peut-être avec « Conneries » ou même « Con » tout seul : « QEDC », comme dans l’exemple qui me vient-là : 
« QEDC, Papa Poule ?!? T’as passé COMBIEN de temps à faire ce commentaire à la con !?! »

Comment: @PapaPoule (+1) J'aime bien. Car effectivement je n'avais encore rien de très convaincant. En date, ta proposition d'acronyme est la meilleure à mes yeux.

Answer (score 37):

> C'est quoi ce bordel ?
>
> Qu'est-ce que tu fous, mec ?

sont les deux expressions qui me viennent à l'esprit pour rapporter une « discussion » un peu vive.

Ne pas le traduire ?  remplacer *bordel* par *bazar* et *fous* par *fais* ? Mais, c'est un peu faux-cul (remplacer par *langue de bois*).

**EDIT**

> Quel merdier !

concis, peut être utilisé à l'écrit à tous les niveaux de l'échelle sociale, et sur différentes intonations.
C'est de la « langue verte », cela peut paraître grossier mais il n'y a pas de connotation vulgaire, au contraire de *t'es en train de foutre ta merde*.

Tout est une question de circonstances et de doigté, et pour les synonymes littéraires :

> Tu parles d’un *bobinard* mon vieil Edmond, quel *bordel* madame Adèle, quel
> *boxon* monsieur Léon.

(*La crosse en l'air* de Prévert)

Comment: Ces propositions alternatives ne sont pas inenvisageables, mais je reste sur ma faim.

Comment: @RomainVALERI - quelques idées en plus pour une traduction littéraire, reste à connaître le contexte orignal.

Comment: +1 Je trouve *merdier* excellent pour la seconde partie de ma question (*a WTF* == *un merdier*)

Comment: Avoir *désaccepté* ta réponse pour accepter la mienne (la deuxième) n'était pas très élégant, je le concède. Mais l'usage idiomatique que je recherchais précisément n'est pas ici malgré la bonne analyse. Excellente réponse au demeurant.

Answer (score 24):

Je souhaiterais fournir ici une perspective québécoise au problème que pose la traduction de cette locution d'ordre familière et somme toute grossière. On remarque que des suggestions mentionnées jusqu'à maintenant se dégagent deux problématiques.

La première concerne le registre : Il peut être de bon aloi de vouloir tempérer le propos en traduisant et d'exercer une prudence afin de ne pas amplifier un langage déjà crû, ce qui serait en quelque sorte travestir le message (voir par exemple l'article du 19 juin 2012 dans The Economist, [*Swearing : Very much lost in translation*](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2012/06/swearing)). La deuxième problématique concerne le bassin culturel duquel tire ses racines le langage cru ou populaire : évocateur pour certains, inconnu pour d'autres.

Pour poursuivre sur cette perspective, le mot *fuck* est employé de manière assez généralisée au Québec, comme en témoigne l'inclusion de ce mot et de quelques-uns de ses dérivés québécisés : *fucker*, verbe; *fucké*, nom et adjectif; etc. (Antidote HD, Druide informatique)

Toutefois, cette expression est non seulement d'un registre familier ou très familier, mais elle reste bien plus utilisée à l'oral qu'à l'écrit, comme en témoigne leur très faible occurrence dans les médias écrits québécois (0 occurrences sur Le Devoir, 107 sur le Journal de Québec). De plus, de nombreuses alternatives existent et demeurent préférées et préférables.

Pour entrer dans le vif du sujet et faire quelques propositions, on peut se tourner vers une thèse aillant aborder indirectement la question en se basant sur le film québéco-ontarien *Bon cop, Bad cop* (2006). Ce film met en scène deux enquêteurs, un Ontarien et un Québécois, et selon la version visionnée (anglaise ou française), une langue est sous-titrée.

> - Dialogue : Qu’essé qu’y câlice ici, la tête carrée?
> - Sous-titre : What the fuck is squarehead doing here?
> - Dialogue : Qu’essé qu’tu câlices icitte?
> - Sous-titre : What the fuck you doing here?
> - Dialogue: Câlice d’hostie de sacrament de ciboire de criss d’hostie de viarge de  tabarnak!
> - Sous-titre proposé (sic) : You goddamn fuckin’ incompetent bastards. What the fuck were  you assholes doing?

(Tiré respectivement des pages 53, 72 et 79 ; Hadley, J-A, [*Translating the Québécois Sociolect for Cinema
– The Creation of a Supertext in Bon Cop Bad Cop*](http://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/7331/1/Hadley_MA_S2011.pdf), thèse non-publiée, 2011)

À noter : « Qu'essé » est une typographie phonologique de « Qu'est-ce que ». On peut aussi remarquer la différence entre les jurons québécois et ceux proposés ci-haut. Ces exemples sont rapportés d'un dialogue oral.

J'irai maintenant de suggestions personnelles pour conclure. À l'écrit, « What the fuck » se traduirait très bien pour un public cible québécois par « Qu'essé! ». Selon le degré d'intensité, on peut l'agrémenter de jurons bien du terroir et fortement inspirés du clergé; par exemple : câlisse, tabarnac, osti (sic). Ainsi, pour « What the fuck is going on? », on pourra utiliser : « Qu'essé qu'y a? ». C'est ainsi que la graphie jouera le rôle important, et répondra aux deux problématiques initiales; elle indiquera un degré de familiarité et ciblera un répertoire culturel.

Bon, après tout cela, j'aurai besoin de me confesser!

Comment: +1 pour contrer le régionalisme français qui est présent sur French.SE.

Comment: Stéphane, your reply put a big smile on my face. You were really funny! Your thought of using dubbing resources gave me an idea (see my reply below). And a beautiful conclusion for your post:-) Thanks for making my day a much better one!

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice the original author was Olivier Lepage:-)

Answer (score 11):

J'aurais simplement opté pour l'[universel « putain »](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSeaDQ6sPs0)  qui correspond bien à l'[universalité de « fuck »](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=588ngaryDJo).

> What the fuck! → *Putain !*
>
> What the fuck is going on? → *Qu'est-ce qui se passe, putain !?*
>
> What the fuck are you doing here? → *Putain ! Qu'est-ce que tu fous là, toi ?*

Maintenant rien n'empêche de varier les plaisirs, avec en y mettant *merde*, *bordel*, *mon dieu !* ou autre.

Plus sérieusement, le plus simple est de ne pas le traduire mais de le retranscrire sous la forme d'une exclamation familière adaptée au contexte et qui transmette l'étonnement avec un pointe d'étonnement.

> What the fuck? → *Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette merde ?*
>
> What the fuck is going on? → *Je comprends que dalle !*
>
> What the fuck are you doing here? → *Qu'est-ce que tu fous là, toi ?*

**Complément**

« *What the fuck* » dérive très certainement d'un jurons plus classique du type « What the hell », on pourrait donc le traduire « que diable », mais ces jurons à connotation religieuse sont tombés en désuétude en France, et n'ont pas donné lieu à des dérivés équivalents à ceux qu'on trouve en anglais.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec l'idée mais... c'est normal parce que c'est à peu de choses près l'idée de départ formulée dans la question. Merci en tout cas pour ta contribution.

Comment: *what the fuck is going on* implique un "in here" qui devrait donc se traduire par un *qu'est ce que c'est que c'bordel?!*

Answer (score 5):

En recherchant à me rapprocher de quelque chose de plus littéral, j'ai repensé à l'expression *que diable* qui pourrait peut-être correspondre à *what the hell*, variante moins grossière de *what the fuck*, et qui a la même forme de construction avec différents adjectifs interrogatifs :

- Que diable lui avez-vous dit ?
- Comment diable êtes-vous entré ici ?
- Pourquoi diable n'avez-vous pas appelé à l'aide ?

Bien sûr, le registre de langage ne correspond pas du tout pour traduire "what the fuck", mais je fais simplement le constat qu'il manque en français l'équivalent dans le registre familier.

> *what the hell* >>> *que diable*
>
> *what the fuck* >>> ?

(On peut également noter la variante *que diantre*, encore plus littéraire et inemployée oralement.)

Comment: Ou leur proche cousin *fichtre*.

Comment: Dans ce genre de registre, je pense qu'il est possible de supprimer *diable* et de précéder la phrase par *putain*.

Comment: @Morwenn +1 Oui, et même si la forme diffère un peu, c'est souvent une bonne solution.

Comment: Pure exclamation d'une haute personnalité (un tantinet coincée) : `Bigre!` - Second degré garanti, verdeur du langage fanée.

Answer (score 5):

Pour la *vulgarité* et l'*agrément*, j'utiliserais ***putain de***, qui semble tout aussi passe-partout, (cf. [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/3067/79)), et qui traduit bien [d'autres occurrences courantes](http://xkcd.com/90/) de la même insanité.

Comme *nom*, ***bordel*** semble tout indiqué. En particulier, ça me semble assez adapté à la deuxième partie de la question, et j'ai déjà entendu parler de « code-bordel ». Je trouve *merdier* pas assez courant pour s'être détaché de son odorante origine, au contraire de *bordel*, *putain* et *fuck*.

***Ce qui me semble le plus important, c'est de traduire combien l'emploi fréquent fait perdre du sens initial des mots.***

Et puisque ça n'a pas encore été suggéré, je mentionnerai `Gni ?`, ou sa variante `Gné?`, s'il s'agit de traduire *WTF?* en tant qu'incompréhension à part entière, qui n'agrémente rien, mais se suffit à elle-même. On se rapproche de *Hein ?*, pour l'interrogation.

Comment: Ah, je vois! Donc vous proposez une onomatopée pour traduire un acronyme... intéressant :)

Comment: +1 pour la réponse dans sa globalité, mais notamment aussi pour la remarque à propos de la fréquence d'emploi.

Answer (score 4):

On peut le traduire de manière non-vulgaire:

> WTF  → C'est [trop] n'imp' !!
>
> WTF-y  → n'importe-quoi-esque

Sinon, je le traduirais comme ceci:

> C'est quoi, ça !?
>
> C'est quoi, c'te truc !?
>
> C'est quoi, c'te merde !?
>
> C'est quoi, ce foutoir !?
>
> C'est quoi, c'te putain de bordel !?

Et ainsi de suite, en rajoutant un éventuel *putain* ou *bordel* au début ou à la fin.

Il y a bien d'autres variantes…

Comment: *n'imp'* a (parfois) déjà un rôle d'adjectif, donc pourrait éventuellement correspondre tel quel pour *WTF-y* dans certains contextes, oui. Mais en substantif ... ? *Du n'imp'* ce n'est pas dénombrable (en dehors de toute autre considération esthétique).

Answer (score 4):

Au Québec, en tout cas, dans ma région, cela pourrait être;

- `« Cé quoi ton problème »`,
- `« Cé quoi l'fuck? »`,
- `« Quessé tu veux? »`,
- `« Quessé qui s'pass? »`.

C'est difficile car cela dépend beaucoup du context, mais dans le context suivant, par exemple, quelqu'un qui n'apprécie pas de se faire regarder et vous lance un `« What the fuck men? »`, au Québec, ce pourrait être tranduit par `« C'est quoi ton problème? »` ou `« C'est quoi, tu cherches le fuck? »`.

Comment: Étrangement, au Québec, c'est exactement dans ce genre de situation/contexte que l'on commence à détruire la langue française avec des mots qui n'existent pas. :P

Comment: Elle est très phonétique, ta réponse... Et je dois dire que les Trifluviens ont de drôles d'expressions. :p

Comment: @SimonDugré Les mots qui n'existent pas, ça n'existe pas! Merci de ta réponse.

Comment: @Kareen Oui j'y suis allé avec des réponses phonétiques. Mais on comprend vite que "Cé quoi l'fuck?" va s'écrire "C'est quoi le fuck". Je voulais simplement peser sur le comment nous le prononçons ici, à Trois-Rivières.

Answer (score 4):

Il existe un contexte et une valeur particulière de l'expression qui n'a pas été abordé dans les réponses jusqu'à présent et dans lequel l'expression, très heureusement, si l'on peut dire, a un équivalent presque exact, tant sur le plan du registre que sur celui du « matériel » ; il faut dire « presque » parce que « fuck » est considéré comme du slang grossier et un mot tabou alors que « foutre » étant vulgaire, peut être considéré comme familier ; le contexte est celui des phrases du type suivant ;

> What the fuck! Let's go there, we'll see what they're doing!

On peut alors traduire comme ceci ;

> Qu'est-ce qu'on en a à foutre !  Allons-y, on verra ce qu'ils font !

Cela s'adapte pour au moins une autre personne du verbe;

*première personne du singulier*

> What the fuck! I'll tell them there is no more boodle!
>    -  Qu'est-ce qu'j'en ai à foutre ! Je leur dirai qu'ya plus d'pognon !

En ce qui concerne la seconde personne, il y aurait une ambiguïté, peut être supprimable par une modification, ou bien l'expression ne pourrait pas être utilisée du tout avec le sens voulu; voir le commentaire de user **Papa Poule**, qui a soulevé la question ; l'exemple initial douteux est préservé ci-dessous de sorte à fournir un test pour qui est  intéressé.

*seconde personne du singulier*

> What the fuck! Throw away those dam shoes and buy new ones!
>    -  Qu'est-ce t'en as à foutre ! Balances ces putains de chaussures et achètes-en des neuves !

Comment: +1 for pointing out this useful sense of WTF in English ([to express nonchalance or the dismissal of any consequences of something one is about to do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_the_fuck)) & especially for so nicely rendering it in French! However, using it in the 2d person (in Eng) makes me wonder if it's there to express this "nonchalance/dismissal of consequences" sense or the sense mentioned by the OP (d'un mélange de colère/de surprise/voire de consternation=astonishment/shock/incredulity/disbelief). Maybe hedging the command would help: "WTF! Maybe you should just throw away..."

Comment: @PapaPoule The problem being pointed out to me I can't but identify it and I agree, this use of this exclamation is not exact or at least it is doubtful or weak; however, after trying your suggestion I'm not convinced of any improvement and do not know what to do any more; I'll just mark it off as uncertain. Thanks for pointing this out, it would have defied my understanding for a long time to come otherwise, no matter the number of reviewings.

Comment: Bravo for finding such an old question, with many answers and nevertheless you managed something new.

Answer (score 2):

Même en langage familier en français il n'y a pas vraiment d'équivalent, *utilisé par tous les milieux*, les usages français restent moins vulgaire :

> Qu'est-ce-que c'est ?

Je trouve ça inapproprié de le traduire littéralement, en essayant à tout pris de mettre un terme vulgaire. Ou à la limite, *WTF* peut se traduire par :

> C'est quoi ce bordel ?

*Une émission porte ce nom d’ailleurs : [Il s'agit d'une émission de radio présentée par Laurent Baffie.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C'est_quoi_ce_bordel_%3F)*

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how this thread came up again - but I'll bite! I am addressing specifically the sub-question regarding WTF dans un contexte informatique.

It is Olivier Lepage who gave me the idea of thinking of it through a different lens - He was using movie dubbing. As an ex-navy officer I was thinking back of equivalent terms, namely SNAFU (not quite the same) and FUBAR (closer). Now, I have never used this, but my father, who was also a navy officer, and my grandfather, who was a zouave in the "Great War," referred many times to "Foutu Pourri d'Avance" (that they used largely in the same manner). In fact, this is how my father taught me what FUBAR meant, quite a few years ago...

Foutu Pourri d'Avance, a legit expression of long time usage, is now sometimes shortened to Foupoudav (never used it, but I read it a few times - possibly from "Saving Private Ryan"?). It seems to me this might work for the use you want to make of it? Whatever coding I do these days I do in an English environment, but I could see myself using this in a French context.

So my suggestion is: Foupoudav.

Sorry abt the English reply - easier not to have to type accents with a QWERTY keyboard:-)

Btw, Romain, I still laugh when I think of that old comment of yours: "A chaque fois qu'un développeur utilise toto pour ne pas avoir à clarifier sa démarche intellectuelle, un petit chaton est assassiné"

Comment: I'll comment on my own post, as what follows is not a substantive part of my reply. I still like Papa Poule's QEDB in terms of (a) its meaning and (b) its attribute of acronym. Imho, its cons are that (1) it starts with QED  which may be a source of confusion, and (2) an acronym works when its readers know what it means. Of course, Foupoudav (7K Google hits + 3K for Foupoudave) is not so widely known:-)

Comment: Intéressant ces vieux souvenirs qui remontent à la surface. Depuis que le service militaire n’est plus obligatoire et que l’Europe va bientôt entrer dans son dernier quart de siècle apaisé, la langue vernaculaire des casernes est intestine.

Answer (score 1):

Trois traductions possibles pour *what the fuck* :

- N'importe quoi !
- On s'en fout (abrégé OSEF)
- C'est quoi ce bordel ?

Comment: OK pour la troisième proposition, mais les deux premières me semblent plus proches de *whatever*, non ?

Comment: *Whatever* signifie plus "quelque soit", me semble-t-il. Pour les 2 premières, je les ai déjà rencontrées. C'est pour ça que je les ai mises.

Answer (score 1):

> Qu'est ce que c'est que ce bordel ?

ou encore

> C'est quoi ce bordel ?

Answer (score 1):

Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette connerie ? - WTF?
Quelle connerie ! - WTF !
Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette connerie putain/bordel! - what the fuck!

Connerie est l'élément le plus pertinent selon moi.

Answer (score 0):

Je traduirais par « C'est quoi ce merdier putain de bordel (ta mère) ? ».

Comment: J'aime bien mais je trouve "Bordel de merde" plus concis.

Comment: génial... la prochaine fois que je verrai l'acronyme CQCMPDB(TM) dans un forum je saurai de quoi il s'agit...

Comment: @mikerodent Peut-être même CQCMPDB™ (remarque dont l'importance valait bien dix ans de réflexion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Dans la mesure où l'expression est de plus en plus "lexicalisée", des traductions moins vulgaires que les "putain", "bordel", etc. s'imposent dans la plupart des cas — ce ne sera pas trahir le registre de langage.

Comment: Oui, en effet, mais lesquelles (traductions moins vulgaires) ? Des exemples sont les bienvenus :-)

Answer (score 0):

Je considère qu'une traduction économique et simple rendra toujours justice au message ainsi qu'au sentiment qu'il accompagne.
C'est pourquoi je traduis cette expression par l'exclamation suivante, suivie de variations possibles :

> Merde, eh quoi ?!
>
> Eh merde, quoi ?!
>
> Merde, quoi ?!
>
> ...

Comment: Torquemada veut "rendre justice au message". Permettez-moi de frissonner ;-)

Comment: Mais .. j'en frissonne encore moi-même.