# What is the French equivalent of "Holy fucking shit"?

Tags: interjections, jurons

By equivalent of "Holy fucking shit," I mean a phrase that:

1. consists mostly of curse words; and
2. is used primarily to indicate disbelief / surprise (as opposed to, e.g., insulting someone or expressing anger).

Edit:  if you look at http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=holy+fucking+shit, you'll see the idea of surprise in most definitions -- you wouldn't use "Holy fucking shit" if you were mad at someone, or expressing anger. (English speakers, do you agree?)

The "bordel de merde" and "putain de merde" answers given below are pretty good, but they aren't prefect:  someone might angrily yell "bordel de merde!" if they dropped a plate in the kitchen, for example, or if their kids were driving them crazy (right?).  People don't use "Holy fucking shit" that way -- never in anger, only in surprise.

Comment: Could be linked to [this one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/comment-traduire-what-the-fuck) ? Maybe not, if you hoped for a somewhat literal translation (which, by the way, won't be easy). Anyway, even if the question is different, some answers could be useful I guess.

Comment: Have you tried asking [the Merovingian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaU3bE7M2UA)?

Comment: Be warned that all of the answers given so far are characteristically European and would provoke hilarity if you ever used them in Canada.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll take the Urban Dictionary definitions and try to show you how the words *putain*, *bordel* and *merde* can fit in any of those situations. To me it's more of a matter of **how you say the words** than a matter of words themselves. Hence my answer is more for spoken French than written French:

### Surprise

One might add *Oh* in front of any of those words and get the "Holy fucking shit they found water on the sun" effect: *Oh putain, il y a de l'eau sur le soleil!* as well as the "Holy fucking shit the car in front of us is braking" effect. Repeating quickly that same word several times will add emphasis to the feeling of surprise and urgency: *Merdemerdemerdemerdemerde*

NB: good parents might say *Oh lala* in front of their kids in the car situation

### Exasperation

The most natural thing I say when something exasperates me is some sort of *Rhoo putaaain...!*. Another way to handle those beautiful words would be to wrap them with *mais* and *quoi*, for example *Mais **merde** quoi!*. The wonderful *Putain de bordel de merde* works quite fine here. This is where the word *bordel* belongs the most

### Indignation

Using those words to convey indignation is very similar to exasperation. It will be said in a more energetic way though: *Mais putain quoi! C'est pas possible!*

### Wonder

To express wonder, once again, those words can be used. If you've been hiking for hours and finally reach this beautiful landscape you've been craving for, you might drop a *ooh meeeerde!* with a big smile on your face.

In short, if you say any of those words with a tone that expresses your feelings, it might just work ;) Thank you for that question, I had never thought of how various usage we have of those words. And there are even more!

Answer (score 15):

Although either "Bordel de merde!" or "Putain de merde!" alone would probably suffice in most situations (see [Reverso](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=holy+fucking+shit&langFrom=en&langTo=fr&langTot=en-fr)), in some rare cases of total disbelief, a combination of the two would be in order to take it from "just" "Holy Shit" all the way to "Holy Fucking Shit": [putain de bordel de merde](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putain_de_bordel_de_merde)!

Comment: +1 for the *very* idiomatic "putain de bordel de merde"

Answer (score 7):

#### Historically

Traditional swearing involving ***holy*** will be :

- ***[Nom de Dieu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nom_de_Dieu)***

  > (Populaire) (Trivial) Juron familier pour exprimer la colère, la surprise, le dépit, etc.
- [***Sacrebleu***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sacrebleu)

  > **Etymologie** :
  >  Altération de [Par le] *sacre de Dieu*, où *bleu* est utilisé par substitut pour éviter le blasphème.
  >   **Interjection** : 
  >   Juron familier marquant l’admiration, la colère ou l’étonnement.
  >
  > > *Sacrebleu, si je m’attendais à te voir ici !*
- All its derivatives : ***[Palsambleu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/palsambleu)*** or ***[Sangbleu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sangbleu)***
- ***[Bon sang](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/bon-sang-palsambleu.php)*** and ***[Bon sang de bonsoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_sang_de_bonsoir)*** (with more about palsambleu too)

---

### Today

More insulting and closer to what you are looking for and being more used nowadays will be :

- ***[Bordel de Dieu](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/11424)*** or even, more raging one, ***Putain de bordel de Dieu***

---

**For your curiosity**

And there is [the curse words list](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocabulaire_du_capitaine_Haddock) of the most known swearing guy in French history ! (capitaine Haddock, friend of Tintin)

Comment: I agree that referring to "Holy" these expressions fit, but if you don't want to look like you travelled in time right from the 19th century, you better not use any of these, with an exception for the first one. OK I might exagerate a bit, but those as the Haddock curse words, are just out of date big time. Probably worth mentionning it before OP uses it :-)

Comment: @Bartdude Yeah, you are right, I'm just placing it here because it is a funny part of the French swearing history ! ;) I have edited to make clear what my answer is

Comment: @Bartdude It is not cristal clear for what usage the OP asks, it may be for an historical novel !

Comment: Indeed, but it might be for trying to fit in a group of French-speaking friends, so better mention it :-) Also I'm actually not sure how modern "Holly f*** shit" is, in my believes this is quite "modern", so I must admit I didn't think about the possibility of an old text...

Comment: @Bartdude I must agree that it is not the best way to look like your are hip (swag I mean !) ;)

Comment: Bande de zapotèques de tonnerre de Brest!  :-)

Comment: Upvoted, but "nom de dieu", "sacrebleu", etc sound too old-fashioned to be a modern equivalent of "holy fucking shit."  Also, several of them are "pour exprimer la colère" in addition to surprise.

Comment: @Adrian It is why I made two titles : **Historically** and **Today**

Comment: @YohannV. ah, good point, I should read more closely.  Does "Putain de bordel de Dieu" sound angry, though?

Comment: @Adrian It may be my personnal experience but I think so (it's why I wrote *"more raging one"*)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, for expressing strong surprise:

> Ouah, la vache!

(or variants like "Oh, la vache!", "Ah, la vache!"). It might perhaps work especially well in movie dubbing.

It also [works in advertising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfY-WuDdThc), because it is socially acceptable (see a very humorous [hijacking of the phrase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZRJxDTg_xs), which shortly became a meme in the 1980s).

Answer (score 1):

> "**Bigre !**"

Attribué à *[Maurice Couve de Murville](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Couve_de_Murville)* face à une situation très embarrassante.
 Ministre des affaires étrangères sous de Gaulle, issu de la [HSP](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haute_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_protestante), ce personnage d'apparence austère, n'était pas dépourvu d'un humour pouvant être féroce.

Answer (score 0):

"Bordel de putain de merde à la con" is probably the most complete swear phrase.

Comment: De mémoire, dans le sketche *Les cintres*, Desproges use de cette presque exacte formule, même un poil plus "complète". Je crois que c'était **Putain de bordel de merde [de cintre] à la con, chié.** Mais en revanche, c'était pour exprimer... la colère. Et en effet, je ne trouve pas que ça exprime la surprise.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the best equivalent is *Putain de bordel de merde*.

Answer (score -1):

« Putain de bordel de merde! » grogna-t-il en se secouant les cheveux avec degoût. « Cet endroit me répugne! »

*p.233, Train d'enfer pour Ange rouge, THILLIEZ, F.*